# CVS export has rows Grouped by certain column headers, how do I flatten it to fill in all the blank cells?

Tags: google-sheets

Exports currently look like this. I can Not change the export to do anything differently. [current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y28uF.png)

I would like to know how to make that first image, look like this second image from inside Google Sheets.
[desired view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWCqw.png)

Im lost, and dont know where to begin.

Comment: I'm downloading the CSV that is available to me to download. It looks like the first photo. Grouped by date and then vendor.  

I want to have all rows have the Date and vendor info, Instead of being grouped that way.

@Tedinoz

Comment: @Tedinoz I am importing to google sheets from csv.

Comment: Got it. OK, we're starting with the basic import then massaging in Google sheets.

Comment: Related questions: [How do I fill down a column, copying the cell above, unless the adjacent cell has a value, then copy that value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62701805/1330560), [Fill Empty Cells With The Same Value as Previous Cell in Google Sheet (Array Formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71646168/1330560)

Comment: Related question (on Web Applications): [Sum of values under a merged Cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/91969/196152)

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in cell F1:

---

```
=query(
 {
  arrayformula(
   query({
    vlookup(
     vlookup(ROW(A2:A9),FILTER(ROW(A2:A9),LEN(A2:A9)),1),
     {FILTER(ROW(A2:A9),LEN(A2:A9)),FILTER(A2:A9,LEN(A2:A9))},2,0),
    vlookup(
     vlookup(ROW(B3:B10),FILTER(ROW(B3:B10),LEN(B3:B10)),1),
      {FILTER(ROW(B3:B10),LEN(B3:B10)),FILTER(B3:B10,LEN(B3:B10))},2,0)
   },
   "select Col1, Col2")
  ),
  query({C3:E11},"select Col1, Col2, Col3")
 },
 "Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 where Col3 is not null 
 label Col1 'Date', Col2 'Vendor', Col3 'PO#', Col4 'Item#', Col5 'Cost' 
 format Col1 'd/M/yy', Col5 '#,##0.00'"
)
```

---

**LOGIC**

The primary logic is an adaptation of a method used by @Ruben in [Sum of values under a merged Cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/91973/196152). This uses a combination of:

- `ARRAYFORMULA`, `VLOOKUP` and `FILTER` to repeat the blank column values.
- The final formula is a `Query` nesting the following:

  - One formula for the `Invoice range` ("A2:A9")
  - One formula for `Vendor range` ("B3:B10")

    - note the difference because of the 1 row offset between the two sets of values.
  - One simple `QUERY` for Columns C:E ("C3:E11" - again the manage the offset).
- `where Col3 is not null` removes any remaining blank rows
- `label` values set for each column
- `format` set for "Date" and "Cost"

---

**DATA**

[image: data]

---

**RESULTS**

[image: results]

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: I've added the original data. The formula goes in Cell F1 (assuming the imported CSV data is in columns A:E).

Comment: I've formatted the formula/answer so that the sequence & the elements are (hopefully) a bit more clear. In particular, the three data ranges should be more obvious and adaptable to your data: `A2:A9`-`1st _DATE_ row to last COST row`, `B3-B11`-`1st _VENDOR_ row to row after last COST row`, `C3-E11`-`1st _VENDOR_ row to 2nd row after last COST row`.